# Using external objects as state properties in React

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I have some external object inside my JavaScript file:

```
var data = [{id: 1, name:'Test1'}, {id:2, name: 'Test2'}];
```

which I pass to ReactDOM:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Test data={data}/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

and as a property to the state object for `Test` component:

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return {localState: data};
},
```

Somewhere along the chain, I use this:

```
handleClick: function () {
        data[0].id=55;
        this.setState({localState: data});
}
```

which causes re-render. Full code here: http://jsfiddle.net/44ff2j4b/

Is this a good idea? Basically, having external data which will be modified in place in the component and re-rendered appropriately. Are there some side effects of doing this? As far as I'm aware, it's not OK to modify state **in the React component**, but the "state" here does not belong to a component...it belongs to the domain logic.

Answer (score 0):

In a React component, "state" is very much supposed to be modified, in-fact state of a component can only be modified within it. However, what you are doing here is seeding the state with a prop and then maintaining it internally. So long as you are not duplicating the prop every-time, merely seeding it, it is ok. Do [read more about this here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html). You should however rename the prop from `data` to `initialData` to indicate that it will only be used for seeding the state.

Answer (score 0):

Although it may work, it is not generally a good idea to do this.

React likes you to **treat props as immutable**. So if you pass data as a prop, you are not supposed to change the original data, like you do in:

```
data[0].id=55;
```

If you want to pass data to a react component, copy it as initial state in `getInitialState()`, and change only the copy inside the react component.
NB: for this, you will need to make a deep copy (so not only copy the array of objects, but also copy the objects themselves). ImmutableJS is a solution/ library often used in conjunction with react.

If you also want to change the original data, the proper way is to pass a **function** as a prop (in addition to the data prop) to the react component. From the react component, you can then call this function, which can then change the original data. The original data change or update should leave your data-copy inside react component intact.
The code (outside react) can then decide whether or not to re-render the entire react component with the new data (but it is standard practice to call `ReactDOM.render()` only once).