# Modifying global variable in react before ReactDOM.render

Tags: reactjs

Take a look at this code: http://codepen.io/FreeCodeCamp/pen/LGbbqj

Basically, the part where you have `function update()` which re-renders the global object using `ReactDOM.render` and then invokes it if a function modifies the global object in place. The whole approach comes to:

1. Have a global state object passed to a root component
2. Modify the object across any component
3. After modifying it, call `ReactDOM.render` to re-render everything

Are there any side effect/performance issues of this approach? I've seen it being used across many codebases. Are there any viable alternatives?

Comment: This type of global object only makes sense during the 'mocking' phase of building an app. In a production app any state that's global would be stored in some type of module or state management system like redux / flux. As a separate note I think you should get rid of all your jQuery and just use React. You're using 'state' only for `showModal` but you can use it for all of your mutable view information.

Comment: Oh maybe this wasn't your pen.. either way calling stuff like `text` is very strange for a React app where data binding already exists and is far easier to work with. To answer your last question: yes the most obvious alternative is handle any global state inside your root component's `state' object.

Comment: @azium Yeah it wasn't my pen, it was from freecodecamp. But this was the most relevant code for the problem I was facing, which is a) Having a global state object which can be simple or very complex with nested objects etc. b) Finding a way to easily modify it at any level. React immutabilitly helpers seem to be of some help, but not enough. I've also found some people using the approach I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35327378/using-external-objects-as-state-properties-in-react . Is there any approach you'd recommend for this without introducing Flux/Redux?